# Vertical placement of grid within a frame while using Grid Geometry Manager in perl-tk

Tags: perl, grid, tk-toolkit, perltk

I'm using a grid within a frame and I want to position the grid towards the bottom of the frame. Currently I'm doing this by placing an addition dummy label on line #4 (#114 [here](http://scsys.co.uk:8002/101533?ln=on&tidy=on&hl=on&submit=Format+it!)). Is there a better way to go about it.

```
    $frm_sig->grid(-row=>0, -column=>0, -sticky=>'news', -padx=>2);
    $frm_sig->gridColumnconfigure(0, -weight=>1);
    {
        $lbl_sig_dummy->grid(-row=>0, -column=>0, -columnspan=>2);
        $rdb_sig_type_se->grid(-row=>1, -column=>0, -sticky=>'w');
        $rdb_sig_type_diff->grid(-row=>1, -column=>1, -sticky=>'w');

        $lbl_sig_val->grid(-row=>2, -column=>0, -sticky=>'w');
        $txt_sig_val->grid(-row=>2, -column=>1, -sticky=>'w');

        $lbl_sign_val->grid(-row=>3, -column=>0, -sticky=>'w');
        $txt_sign_val->grid(-row=>3, -column=>1, -sticky=>'w');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to move the *rest* of the grid to the bottom by setting a non-zero weight on just the first row, without filling it with a dummy label or frame (but if you want something there, that's absolutely fine):

```
$frm_sig->gridRowconfigure(0, -weight=>1);
```

With a new enough Tk, you can anchor the whole gridded area to one edge of its containing widget, but I don't know if you've got a new enough version.

Comment: Donal, thanks for the solution; it works like a charm. Also, I'm using Tk 8.0

Comment: Tk 8.0? Oh my, that's like over a decade old (unless Perl::Tk isn't tracking Tk versions closely, which would just be confusing).

Comment: Donal, actually I'm using 804.029; Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We have to be careful about versions; Tk has its own version and the Perl::Tk library has a separate version too. Tk 8.0 is utterly ancient now – though there might still be some of my code somewhere that uses it :-) – but you're more likely using 8.4 under the hood which is just a bit old…